# TimerTask does not stopped instantly android

Tags: android, timer, android-service, timertask

I have two services which run periodically based on condition. In once condition the services are run with 5 second timer while in other they run with 10 mins timer.

But when I want to switch from 5 second to 10 mins timer, it does not happen instantly while it runs 4 times extra. I am canceling timer pefectly but does not seems like working..here is code

```
 public final static Handler serviceHandler = new Handler(){

        public void handleMessage(Message msg){
            if(null != serviceTimer) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Coming insisisi");
                serviceTimer.cancel();
                serviceTimer.purge();
                serviceTimer = null;

            }
            serviceTimer = new Timer();
                serviceTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new serviceMonitorAcc(service, target), DELAY_TIMER_TIME, TIMER_START_TIME);
                serviceTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new serviceMonitorTrafficStats(service, target), DELAY_TIMER_TIME, TIMER_START_TIME);

            Log.d(TAG, "TIMER STATTAA"+serviceTimer);
        }
    };
```

based on conditions I set the values of variable DELAY_TIMER_TIME and TIMER_START_TIME

```
 private void setTimerInfo(String check){
    if(check != null) {
        if (check.equals("enable")) {

            DELAY_TIMER_TIME = 0;
            TIMER_START_TIME = 5000;
        } else {

            DELAY_TIMER_TIME = 60000;
            TIMER_START_TIME = 600000;
        }
    }
}
```

the time setting working time only issue is it does not get killed instanlty and start new serviceTimer with new timer setting.

I also tried to kill timertask serviceMonitorAcc and serviceMonitorTrafficStats separatly, but did not work ...any suggestion or pointer for it...

Comment: use serviceTimer.purge() to remove the pending tasks from queue

Comment: I am using in the above code...but seems like not working